# ScrollView with two views, first view filling screen

Tags: android

I would like to have a ScrollView with a LinearLayout containing two views. The first view should occupy the full screen, with the second view initially off the screen (but it can be scrolled to). Is this achievable?

Comment: down voters when you down vote a question please do find time to comment why down voted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/f1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#468432" >

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/f2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff8222" >

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and your activity gose like following

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams; 
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        LinearLayout layout ;
        FrameLayout f1,f2;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linlayout);
            f1=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.f1);
            f2=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.f2);
            ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
                @Override 
                public void onGlobalLayout() { 
                    layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
                    int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
                    int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

                    f1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
                    f2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
                } 
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: If below the first (full-screen) FrameLayout you want to add elements (like TextViews etc.) whose height is not equal to that first FrameLayout, it's better to set the listener to the ScrollView and measure its height, not the LinearLayout. Then, gravity is not needed, and the contents below the first FrameLayout can be anything (you can remove the second FrameLayout).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a ScrollView, a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) is more suited to your needs. Also, since you want it to be vertical, you should check this out: [Directional ViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager)

Comment: If he wants to scroll(which is what he said) between the two pages (and keep the scroll between the two pages) then a `ViewPager` isn't the answer.

Comment: @Luksprog well, he said he wanted to use a ScrollView, but not why, he did say he wanted one fullscreen layout visible and one not immediately visible, I don't see why he would need to force them to pages, but also need them to expand the whole screen, he could have just nested 2 LinearLayouts in his ScrollView then. It seems like he just wanted to force paging into a ScrollView...

Answer (score 0):

I had the hardest time once trying to achieve this in the iphone, maybe the ideas will help you. What I had was a background view with a notebook style set of lines, and a view on top of that with text, and of course they had to scroll together. I added both to the ScrollView and just intercepted the "scrollViewDidScroll" for view1 and did a view2.contentOffset=view2.contentOffset so that they stayed 'glued'. i just started on Android so I wouldn't know how to exactly achieve this there, but I think the principle wouldn't be much different. Hope this helps :)