# Why is my Android Scrollview not scrolling?

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-layout-weight

For some reason scrolling is not getting activated. I want to have that black place cover half the screen also. But if I change that height of ScrollView to wrap content then this black space disappears.

This black space will have photo thats why I need it to cover at least half.

I used layout weight for it but because the pictures are dynamicly loaded I have to reserve the space. Currently in this code it reserves half of the screen but Scrool does not get activated and other items are not visible.

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#e0e0e0"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.example.Test.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e0e0e0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/level1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#e0e0e0"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:background="@color/vk_white">


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:background="@color/black"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />


        </FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/level2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/vk_white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temelBilgilerInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/temelbilgileriinfo"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/layout_root"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/temelBilgilerInfo"
            android:background="@drawable/ruhesi_lines" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_root"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthday"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit1"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthday"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthday"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit3"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthday"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit4"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthday1"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit5"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthday123213"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit7"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit6"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit8"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit7"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit9"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit8"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit10"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit9"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit11"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit10"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit12"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit11"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit13"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit12"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter asd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmGvG.jpg)

Comment: You set the height of the `ScrollView` to `wrap_content`? Why? What do you think `wrap_content` does other then telling the `ScrollView` to be as big as its child? Of course that doesn't work.

Comment: This is the current code. In this code there is no scrolling functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is also located:

[ScrollView with two views, first view filling screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825116/scrollview-with-two-views-first-view-filling-screen)

What I did was to programmaticly  arrange that space for the pager. This part of the other answer was useful for me.

```
    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linlayout);
        f1=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.f1);
        f2=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.f2);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onGlobalLayout() { 
                layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
                int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
                int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

                f1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
                f2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

i check your xml layout and I see that you don't close the ScrollView Correctly.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e0e0e0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
       >
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temelBilgilerInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"

            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/layout_root"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/temelBilgilerInfo"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_root"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthday"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit1"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthday"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthday"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit3"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthday"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit4"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthday1"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit5"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthday123213"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit7"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit6"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit8"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit7"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit9"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit8"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit10"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit9"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit11"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit10"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit12"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit11"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthday_edit13"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit12"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter asd"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

this code goes inside your Scrollview hope it helps!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Actually I forgot it was in my code. It doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: there is no log error it is layout issue. In tinder for example there is profile section there is image gallery and other is data below we can scroll.
In this stuff above I cannot scroll.

Comment: If I turn layout_height to wrap content then I can scroll but the black screen dissappears.