# Android scrollview with viewpager layout_weight issue

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, scrollview

First of all this is the code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/com_facebook_blue"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.example.Test.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/level2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#e0e0e0"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rela"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:background="#e0e0e0">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@mipmap/ruhesi_delete"

                />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/writeButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/deleteButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/deleteButton"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@mipmap/ruhesi_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/writeButtons"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/deleteButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/deleteButton"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"

                android:src="@mipmap/ruhesi_confirm"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/temelbilgiler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rela"

            android:background="#e0e0e0"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/temelBilgilerInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:text="@string/temelbilgileriinfo"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/layout_root"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/temelBilgilerInfo"
                android:background="@drawable/ruhesi_lines" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/birthday_edit"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_root"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Enter Birthday"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/birthday_edit1"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Enter Birthday"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/birthday_edit2"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Enter Birthday"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/birthday_edit3"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Enter Birthday"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/birthday_edit4"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Enter Birthday1"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

         <EditText
                android:id="@+id/birthday_edit5"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit4"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Enter Birthday123213"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/birthday_edit6"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit5"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/birthday_edit7"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/birthday_edit6"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Enter Birthdayasdasdasd"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.isseiaoki.simplecropview.CropImageView
            android:id="@+id/cropImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            custom:backgroundColor="@color/base"
            custom:cropMode="ratio_4_3"
            custom:frameColor="@color/frame"
            custom:frameStrokeWeight="1dp"
            custom:guideColor="@color/guide"
            custom:guideShowMode="show_on_touch"
            custom:guideStrokeWeight="1dp"
            custom:handleColor="@color/handle"
            custom:handleShowMode="show_always"
            custom:handleSize="8dp"
            custom:minFrameSize="150dp"


            custom:overlayColor="@color/overlay"
            custom:touchPadding="8dp" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thumbnails"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="2dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/animatedGifImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In this case this image occurs: Scroll does not work here.
[Scroll does not work here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTxdf.jpg)

Now when I do wrap_content at layout_height of the scrollview then the scrollview works.
The issue then the blue screen part dissappears (viewpager place)

I need that placeholder because there will be image there.

I cannot give fix height for the viewpager because in each device there is different sizes. Thats why I use layout_weight.

How I can have this scroll working and also keep this blue colored place as spaceholder.

Comment: Try using the new CoordinatorLayout, if you can in your scenario.

Comment: Answer is located: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209107/why-is-my-android-scrollview-not-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting either height or width of layout to 0 and then layout weight on whichever one you want to give weight to (height or width). I am a beginner so this might not work in your case however, it looks like it may be an issue if not THE issue.